# Are cospectral/non-cospectral non-isomorphic graphs similar?

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Suppose you have two adjacency matrices $A$ and $B$ of cospectral but non-isomorphic graphs. Is there a matrix $Q$ such that $$A=Q^{-1}BQ$$ holds?

Note if $A$ and $B$ are not cospectral we cannot have a $Q$ such that  $$A=Q^{-1}BQ$$ holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two real symmetric matrices are similar if and only if they have the same characteristic polynomial. So if two graphs are cospectral, their adjacency matrices must be similar.

Comment: what of i interpret adjacencies as in $\Bbb F_p$?

Comment: @Turbo: in finite characteristic, having the same characteristic polynomial does not imply similarity. In this case $A$ and $B$ are similar if and only if $tI-A$ and $tI-B$ have the same Smith normal form.

Answer (score 1):

Since you assume A and B are co-spectral adjacency matrices, they are real symmetric matrices with spectral decompositions $$A= X^{-1} \Lambda X $$  and $$B=Y^{-1} \Lambda Y$$ where $X$ and $Y$ are orthogonal matrices and $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues on the diagonal.

Then $Q=Y^{-1}X$ is your desired matrix.